# RewriteBase Hide the directory? Wordpress directory

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a WordPress site and I made it in a folder like this:

```
site.com/new/
```

In the principal path I have nothing, so when I get access into an article, I see the URL like this:

```
site.com/new/article-1
```

I would like to hide the base path and see something like this:

```
site.com/article-1
```

The default htaccess is this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /new/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /new/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this without needing of `.htaccess` rules.

Just move `index.php` and `.htaccess` from `new` folder to one level up (basically parent) directory.

Then open your `index.php` file and modify this line:

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

to

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/new/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Notice the `new/` folder? This will look for Wordpress core files inside that folder.

And your `.htaccess` to this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Just removed the `new/` directory.

And thats it, visit `site.com`.

One thing to notice when you visit `site.com/new` you may see all the Wordpress directories/files listing. To avoid that create a `.htaccess` file inside the `new` folder and paste this content:

```
Options -Indexes
```

**P.S:** You need to modify your urls in database to work with new one.